# Is there a way to see the total number of clones for a repository on GitHub?

Tags: github

For now through 'traffic' it's possible to see some partial data, i.e. the number of clones in a two week interval but I haven't found a way to get the total number of clones for my own repo.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, it's impossible for now. You can check the numbers of clones in a two week.